# How does Chrome choose its start up locale?

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome, registry

I'm trying to write a small C# program that will allow me to change the locale of different types of browsers. By modifying the current user's locale and locale name in the registry, I've been able to get IE to change its locale, but no such luck with Chrome. I've dug around in the registry and in Chrome's config files, but I haven't been struck by anything. Googling has just brought up ways to change Chrome's locale using Chrome apps; this is not an option for me.

Can anyone help me understand how Chrome decides which locale to use?

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, under `Settings > Show advanced settings` you're able to set the language.

Using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) I've found out that Chrome stores its user preferences in this file:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
```

Using [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) I've found out that it manipulates several `current_locale` values (two in my case) in that file which reflect the locale used by Chrome for that user.

[image]

Comment: I think this is probably on the right track, but these preferences get overwritten upon launching Chrome. And I am not able to use the GUI to change these settings because this functionality will end up in an automated test suite.

It looks like you've exposed me to some interesting new tools to try out though :)

Comment: Are you sure it is upon launch and not at exit?

Comment: That seems to be the behavior I've observed. If I manually modify that text file, when I launch Chrome it will revert the changes I made. Sometimes it's not instantaneous, but it's certainly before I exit.

Answer (score 2):

I have just hacked, simply. Got the file
en-US.pak
from
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\80.0.3987.163\Locales
And copied over the file
pt-BR.pak

And relaunched chrome. Worked for me. I´m using it as a workaround, since my browser is corporate administered, but i have to see some messages in English, not pt-BR

Comment: have a backup of the original file, en-US.pak, is a good idea too...

Answer (score 0):

In my company, someone has installed Google Chrome using a PT-PT EXE installer, but we're using Windows in PT-BR language. Even uninstalling it and installing Google Chrome using the MSI installer, all users that were launching the Chrome at the first time has as language default the PT-PT language locale. The solution was renaming/removing the file "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\master_preferences", so it fallback to the OS language instead of using the default language from the EXE installer.